# In a new, well built house, what is a typical amount to plan to shim cabinets?

Tags: wood, tile, installation, cabinets, shimming

Do you normally end up shimming 1/4" or less?  Or can even a well built house end up as high as 5/8" or 3/4" over 15 feet?  I just don't have a sense of what is "typical" to expect.

What about when installing cabinets over tile?  Would you allow more shimming?  Or just don't use shims at any high spots in the tile?

I have some places that I have to hit (windowsills and tile backsplash. We're afraid of not having enough play for shimming so we're making the cabinets shorter than we could.  But I think we're going overboard :-)  Thanks!

Comment: “Typical” is what you measure you need in your case.

Comment: Was your house custom built by a high-end, well respected builder or was it thrown up as one of 20 built last month in the neighborhood? It's going to depend a lot on the amount of time spent getting everything right and the amount of care and pride taken by the crews working on the house.

Comment: It's a custom home built in a high end modular factory.  I saw them starting to lay the 30x30 floor tiles and they "looked" great, very thin grout lines, appeared to be flat.  The modules are extremely beefy compared to normal construction because they have to be in order to ship them so framing should be straight and stout.  So I would expect this job to be very high quality.  

But I'm still not sure what that means to shimming cabinets.  Is a good job going to be 1/8" variation and a lousy job 1/2"?

Comment: based on a low sample size of 4 or 5, i'd concur that 1/8th" good, 1/4" avg, and 1/2" poor.

Comment: You could easily be out 3/4" in a new house over 15'.  Even if your foundation wall is perfect, depending on the layout of the joists and the span of the joists, assuming you are using dimensional joists and not I-joists the joists have crowns which over 15' can add up.